# Right to Left text functionality Kendo UI Html5 Charts

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have try to implement right to Left text functionality for the KendoUI html5 charts by using
css(**kendo.rtl.css**) provided by KendoUI library.But the chart is completely broken? We can’t fix that issue because we have no control over the SVG. I have tried the same thing for the Grids.It's working fine. Is kendo UI supports Right to Left functionality for the charts? if it's how can I implement this functionality for the charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from Telerik Team :  **'At this point RTL support is not available in the Kendo UI DataViz suite (this feature is supported in Kendo UI Web only).'**